# Difference between these two integrals?

Tags: integration

Recently I failed at computing this simple integral: 
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos{x} \cdot e^{-jx} $$ 
After asking for help here I managed to solve it with 
$ \cos{x} = \frac{e^{jx}+e^{-jx}}{2} $ 
$$ \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos{x} \cdot e^{-jx} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{e^{jx}+e^{-jx}}{2} \cdot e^{-jx} $$
But I still have one problem: As these two integrals should be mathematically identical why did I fail to compute the first one (it leads to an undefined expression) but it works for the second one ($\frac{1}{4}$).
Examples here: 
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} e^{-jx} \cdot \cos(x) dx = \frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot \Bigg[\frac{e^{-jx}}{(-j)^2+1}\cdot[(-j)\cdot \cos(x) + \sin(x)]\Bigg]^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2} $$ 
$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{e^{jx}+e^{-jx}}{2} \cdot e^{-jx} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \Bigg( \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} 1 + \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{-2jx}\Bigg) $$ $$ = \frac{1}{2\pi} \cdot \Bigg(\frac{1}{2} \cdot \Bigg[x\Bigg]^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{\frac{-\pi}{2}} +\frac{j}{4}\cdot\Bigg[e^{-2jx}\Bigg]^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\Bigg) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot \frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$$
Usually reforming expressions resulted in less error prone ones. But I never experienced that reforming an expression made a not solvable expression solvable. Where is the difference here? Beside the fact that the first one fails.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you have the indeterminate form $\frac 00$.  The expression inside the square brackets is $\frac j{1+(-j)^2}$ which has a zero in the denominator.  Since it is a constant its value at $x=\frac \pi 2$ and $x=-\frac \pi 2$ is the same, which effectively gives a zero in the numerator.  You could take the integral of $e^{ax}\cos(x)dx$, evaluate it the way you did for $a \neq -j$, compute it through the substitution of the endpoints, and take the limit as $a \to -j$.  I haven't done it, but I believe that would give the same answer.